# Increment a number by prefix and postfix operator

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, operators, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

By mistake, I wrote:

```
++number++;
```

and got this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

Why? I would except this to to first increment `number` by one and then increment `number` by one again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaScript, `++` is both the *prefix* and *postfix* increment operator. The *postfix* operator has higher precedence, and so when we apply precedence, your expression becomes:

```
++(number++);
```

The result of `number++` is a value, not a variable reference, and so it cannot be the operand of the prefix increment operator, for the same reason `++42` is invalid — there's nowhere to write the result back to.

---

Why does it call it the "left-hand side expression" when it's to the *right* of the operator? You'd have to look at the V8 source code (I can tell from the text of the error you're doing this on V8, probably Chrome). I can *speculate* that it's because many operators accept two operands (left and right), and that they just call the only operand to unary operators like `++` the "left-hand" by default. But that's speculation.

Comment: I must wait 9 minutes to accept the answer, as you know. I didn't know that. Especially that the postfix has greater precedence over the prefix, it's something I didn't expect! Thanks T.J.! Yes, I am in Chrome!

Comment: @gsamaras: I have to admit I had to look the precedence up. :-) I knew what the basic issue was, but not which had higher precedence. [MDN to the rescue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) (since figuring out precedence from the specification itself is...awkward). MDN isn't always correct, but it has a good solid record.