# Getting the count from a switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with getting my returned count to be changed, after I run it through a switch statement. My code looks like following:

```
var count = 0;
                switch ($(this).last().data('card')) { // Regulating the count to be higher/lower  
                // Hearts
                case 'h2':
                    return count++;
                case 'h3':
                    return count++;
                case 'h4':
                    return count++;
                case 'h5':
                    return count++;
                case 'h6':
                    return count++;
                case 'h10':
                    return count--;
                case 'hj':
                    return count--;
                case 'hq':
                    return count--;
                case 'hk':
                    return count--;
                case 'ha':
                    return count--;

                    // Spades
                case 's2':
                    return count++;
                case 's3':
                    return count++;
                case 's4':
                    return count++;
                case 's5':
                    return count++;
                case 's6':
                    return count++;
                case 's10':
                    return count--;
                case 'sj':
                    return count--;
                case 'sq':
                    return count--;
                case 'sk':
                    return count--;
                case 'sa':
                    return count--;

                    // Diamonds
                case 'd2':
                    return count++;
                case 'd3':
                    return count++;
                case 'd4':
                    return count++;
                case 'd5':
                    return count++;
                case 'd6':
                    return count++;
                case 'd10':
                    return count--;
                case 'dj':
                    return count--;
                case 'dq':
                    return count--;
                case 'dk':
                    return count--;
                case 'da':
                    return count--;

                    // Clubs
                case 'c2':
                    return count++;
                case 'c3':
                    return count++;
                case 'c4':
                    return count++;
                case 'c5':
                    return count++;
                case 'c6':
                    return count++;
                case 'c10':
                    return count--;
                case 'cj':
                    return count--;
                case 'cq':
                    return count--;
                case 'ck':
                    return count--;
                case 'ca':
                    return count--;
            }
        })();

        console.log(count);
```

When I'm trying to console log it out, it simply outputs 0. It doesn't solve the problem, even if I replace the jQuery with 'h2'.

I hope someone can help me out :-)

Comment: I tried to do that earlier which didn't help it out. I've been trying to find other ressources for the answer, where the way I've set it up at the moment would do the same as using the break; and then returning count in the end of the function.

Comment: Your code contains a huge amount of copy-pasta. Consider refactoring so that you just detect if the second character is a digit or not. One solution is `count += /[hsdc]\d+/.test($(this).data('card')) ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: if even using `break` instead of `return`, then that means not any case was caught. So `count` still kept the init value of `0`.

Comment: BTW, do you really understand this `$(this).last()`? That makes no sense, `this` should be just one element.

Comment: @KingKing I took a look at it again and could see the "problem". What I meant was to just insert a class into the jQuery selector. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I'm trying to console log it out, it simply outputs 0.

well you're doing postfix increment:

`return count++;`

this will return the value of `count` then increment the value of `count`.

**same goes for this also:**

```
return count--;
```

this will return the value of `count` then decrement the value of `count`.

To overcome the problem simply:

```
return ++count;
```

and also

```
return --count;
```

[**`Postfix` and `Prefix` operators**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795850/increment-a-number-by-prefix-and-postfix-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Use `++count` and `--count` instead. These will increment and decrement the value before returning it. Your code returns the current `count` value of 0 and does not do anything afterwards.

[The difference between ++someValue and someValue++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Incremental operators when suffixed will increment the value **after**.

So...
`return count++;` will return `count`, and then increment it.

You can prefix the incremental operator to increment **before** the action happens.

`return ++count;`

Decremental operators (`--count`) work the same way.

You can view this fiddle as a sample of usage:
https://jsfiddle.net/fjgo4Lwv/

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm not answering your question directly. I just feel like I might be able to help you refine your code to something a bit (a lot) easier to work with. It might even help you towards better solutions for the next card manipulations that you might have to perform.

All of that switching... it's was a pain to write, and will be a pain to maintain.

With a bit of string manipulation and a few pre-defined arrays, you can make life a whole deal easier for yourself:

```
//var cardValue="c10"; //for instance

var suits = ["s", "h", "d", "c"];
var upCards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
var downCards = ["10", "j", "q", "k", "a"];

var suit = cardValue.substr(0, 1); //"c"
var card = cardValue.substr(1); //"10"

var count = 0;

if(upCards.indexOf(card) >= 0){
  count++; //postfix operator doesn't do what you think it does, see other answers
}
if(downCards.indexOf(card) >= 0){
  count--;
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `++` postfix operator increments its operand *after* the operation that contains it. It more concrete terms, if you do

```
var x = 0;

var y = (function incrementX() {
  return x++;
})()

console.log(y) //prints 0
console.log(x) //prints 1
```

the `++` actually runs ***after*** the `return`. So the value that gets returned and stored in `y` is the old value of `x`.

The `++` *prefix* operator does what you want. It increments its operand *before* the rest of the operation. So your code should work if you replace `count++` by `++count`.

The `--` operator behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Switch is not the best choice to use for this case, for is better, but for your learning, you can write switch like this. break or return either one is fine for breakout switch base on your requirement

```js
var count = 0;
var count2 = (function() {
  switch ($(this).last().data('card') || "h2") { // Regulating the count to be higher/lower  
    // Hearts
    case 'h2':
    case 'h3':
    case 'h4':
    case 'h5':
    case 'h6':

    case 's2':
    case 's3':
    case 's4':
    case 's5':
    case 's6':
      return count++;
    case 'h10':
    case 'hj':
    case 'hq':
    case 'hk':
    case 'ha':

      // Spades
    case 's10':
    case 'sj':
    case 'sq':
    case 'sk':
    case 'sa':
      return count--;
  }
})();

console.log(count);
console.log(count2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```